# AngularJS - Not showing new values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have one **test01.html** page. When I click on Next button of test01.html page they call one Java Service and that service return one `key`, name is `changeList` and I just display this key value into my test01.html page using below code

```
{{::serviceErrorMsg}}
```

But problem is that when I click on Next button for the first time my `changeList` key value display into my HTML page is correctly but when I again click on Next button it displays the old value into that page whereas my key value is changed.

My **test01.html** page Code

```
<form name="profInfoForm" ng-submit="saveInfo(profInfoForm)" novalidate>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <section class="main-ctr">
        <div class="error-msg" ng-show="showErrorMsg">
          <div class="text">
            Please fix the validation error(s) below and try again.<br />
            {{::serviceErrorMsg}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
        <main class="sm-main">
          <section class="fix-section">
            <h1>Professional information</h1>
            <div class="lg-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-label lg-label">Test</label>
                <div class="select-wrap lg-select">
                  <select class="form-input select" placeholder="Select Test"
                          ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in salutations"
                          ng-model="profInfo.test">
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="button-ctr">
            <button class="button"
                    ng-class="profInfoForm.$valid ? 'active' : 'disable'">
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </main>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My app.controllers.js Code:

```
.controller('professionalInfoCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'globalService', 'APP_CONSTANTS', 'dataServices', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, globalService, APP_CONSTANTS, dataServices) {
  $scope.showLoader = false;
  $scope.selectedProfession = globalService.getProfessionalType();
  var userData = globalService.getUserData();

  $scope.saveInfo = function (formName) {
    $scope.showErrorMsg = false;
    $scope.formName = formName;
    if ($scope.formName.$invalid) {
      $scope.showErrorMsg = true;
      return;
    }

    dataServices.verifyProfessionalInfo($scope.profInfo).then(function (res) {
      $state.go(res.redirectURL);
    }, function (res) {
      $scope.showErrorMsg = true;
      console.log(res.changeList);
      $scope.serviceErrorMsg = res.changeList;
    });
  }
}]);
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

I am using `AngularJS v1.5.5` with `Java Service`.

Comment: can you verify it by removing :: sign ? that restricts 2 way data binding

Comment: :: will restrict two binding, hope removing :: will help

Comment: @VinodLouis Yes you right, Thanks for the help. :)